# Binding multiple ComboBoxes to the same ItemsSource causes problems

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, itemssource

I have 2 `ComboBoxes` whose `ItemsSource` is bound to the same `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyType> MyTypeCollection { get; set; }
```

I have defined 2 different `SelectedItem` properties which in turn are bound to the correct `ComboBox`.

```
public MyType MySelectedItem1 { get; set; }
public MyType MySelectedItem2 { get; set; }
```

Whenever I select an item in one of the `ComboBoxes`, both `SelectedItem` properties defined in my class are set to that selection. Both `ComboBoxes` are also set visually to that value.

Why is this?

I tried several things like `Mode=OneWay` etc, but it's not working.

Here's my XAML (trimmed down for the question):

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem1}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyTypeCollection, Mode=OneWay}"/>

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem2}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding MyTypeCollection, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Your post says your Xaml is "trimmed down".  Did the original version by chance have `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on the combo boxes?  If so, that's your problem.

Comment: @MikeStrobel Yes they have, removing them from XAML solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm guessing you have `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` on both `ComboBox` controls.  Remove it from both, and that should solve your problem.

Setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` tells the `ComboBox` that it should keep its `SelectedItem` in sync with the `CurrentItem` in the underlying `ICollectionView`.  Since you are binding directly to a collection, and not a collection view, both combo boxes are using the default collection view, which is a common instance shared across controls.  When one of your combo boxes updates the collection view's selection, the other sees the change and updates its own selection to match it.